# Load image from url save it as byte

Tags: c#, image, arrays, html-agility-pack

I getting one image with HTMLAgilityPack and then I want to load it as byte so I could save it in database.

```
byte[] bIMG = File.ReadAllBytes(doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//img[@class='image']").Attributes["src"].Value);
```

But it says `URI formats are not supported.` how else I can do that?

EDIT: **doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//img[@class='image']").Attributes["src"].Value** gives a link

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `System.IO.File` class can't read web URIs - you can use the WebClient for this:

```
byte[] imageAsByteArray;
using(var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    imageAsByteArray = webClient.DownloadData("uri src");
}
```

Comment: Might want to wrap `webClient` in a `using` block.

Comment: Ah, well caught - yes, the WebClient is IDisposable. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks , but i get `The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.`